# Insert values from csv file with no header to a SQL table with headers

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have a csv file with no headers and created one SQL table with fields A, B, C, D and E. I need to import the data from the csv file into the table on python.

```
file = open(path)
data = csv.reader(file)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = '''INSERT INTO table (id1, id2, name, birthday, score) VALUES (?,?, ?,?,?)'''
cursor.executemany(insert_movies, data)
cursor.close()
connection.commit()
```

I have also tried to loop through the rows

```
file = open(path)
data = csv.reader(file)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = '''INSERT INTO table (id1, id2, name, birthday, score) VALUES (?,?, ?,?,?)'''
for row in data:
    cursor.executemany(query, row)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: You've showed us some code. How is it failing to do what you want? Do you get an error message? Please read [ask].

Comment: Note that your table has _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this on Jupyter instead of visual code and it ran. Actually the output of this table was feeding into another which was showing no elements. But after running on Jupyter the same code generated the table. Not sure what the actual cause was.